# mute the player app in android

Tags: android, media, volume, mute

In my app, I have mute button and there are some codes in onClick event:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
```

I expect, only mute my app but it make mute system. 
How I can fix it? Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
```

Comment: It makes both my app and system mute. I expect, only mute my app but not system.